# Download File From FTP USing ftp4j

Tags: android

I know how to upload a file using ftp4j however I would like to use the same method for downloading a file from FTP, I expect to see:

1. server directory (httpdocs/folder/to/download/from/file.extension)
2. local directory (/sdcard/folder/to/download/to/file.extension)

Here is the code I use to upload:

```
file_destination = new File(filDir +"/"+fileName); // where fileDir + filename = sdcard/document/file.txt

private void uploadImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    file_destination_string = file_destination.toString();
    upload_file = new File(file_destination_string);
    uploadFile(upload_file);

}
    private void uploadFile(File f) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        client = new FTPClient();
        try {
            client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);            //where HOST is ip address of server
            client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);           // FTP user / password
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            client.changeDirectory(FTP_DIR);            //where FTP_DIR = /httpdocs/folder/
            client.upload(f, new MyTransferListener());     

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FTP Failed: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("e1..."+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                client.disconnect(true);  

                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
                System.out.println("e2...");
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.println("e3...");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {

        public void started() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Upload Started ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void transferred(int length) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " transferred ..." + length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void completed() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " completed ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void aborted() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," transfer aborted, please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void failed() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

How can I download a file?

Comment: you can just use `client.download("myfile.txt", new java.io.File("d:/myfile.txt"));` This will download "myfile.txt" to "D:\myfile.txt".

Comment: I am trying to upload and download to and from an android device not on PC

Comment: easy, just replace "D:\myfile.txt" with "/sdcard/myfile.txt"

Comment: Worked thanks, I'm using it with a FTPDataTransferListener for progress bytes

Comment: Nice. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a download method available.

you can just use `client.download("myfile.txt", new java.io.File("d:/myfile.txt"));` This will download "myfile.txt" to "D:\myfile.txt".

For android, the whole thing is slightly diffrent.
If you want to store the file on a defined folder (for Example on the sdcard), you can just use it like this:

`client.download("myfile.txt", new java.io.File("/sdcard/myfile.txt"));`

If you want do download it to the apps default data directory, you can use the method `context.getExternalFilesDir()`. If you pass `null` as parameter, this returns the root directory for your app's private directory on the external storage.

More information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Additionally, to quote AndroidDevelopers here:

> Starting in `KITKAT`, no permissions are required to read or write to
>   the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This
>   only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling
>   application. To access paths belonging to other packages,
>   `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and/or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are required.

So you don't need this two permissions to access your own applications files.

Finally, this code should download a file and just create a new file in your apps default directory:

`client.download("myfile.txt", new java.io.File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "myfile.txt"));`

Answer (score 0):

I see downlod method in their API.

```
 void   download(java.lang.String remoteFileName, java.io.File localFile) 
          This method downloads a remote file from the server to a local file.
```

Here is the API link - http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/FTPClient.html